# Making a QPROPERTY read only in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a property which does some calculation over the variable, but I don't want the reflected variable to reflect the UI, so I just need to do some calculations but the final result shouldn't reflect the UI in the property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't add a write accessor, e.g.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int myVar READ myVar NOTIFY myVarChanged) //No WRITE ...

public:
    int myVar() const;

signals:
    void myVarChanged(int myVar);

private:
    int m_myVar;
}
```

Comment: I did it like that, but its still reflecting the GUI. I'm doing myVar = 14; and it still reflected in the GUI

Comment: You will have to make myVar member private - see the updated answere. This way it gets impossible to set it from outside

Comment: its set to private, but in the class that it uses that variable I do some calculations on that variable, and it reflects the GUI at the end showing the final value of the variable after calculations

Comment: Well, thats a totally diferent concept. Just create 2 properties, one that keeps the initial value, and one that is used for the calculations. This automatic reflection is what properties are intended for

Comment: `Q_PROPERTY` can be set only if `MEMBER` or `READ` accessors of it are specified.

Comment: if the property isn’t supposed to be seen in the UI, it might be questionable why it should be a property at all, instead of just a private member variable.